# Use LoDash in Angular to find objects from localData

Tags: angularjs, lodash

I am new to LoDash. I am just trying to find an object inside of localData, but I kept failing.  I couldn't figure it out where the problem is. I could use _chain and fratten functions to filter my object, but after I applied find, the error occurs: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token".

Below is my code:  Could any of you help?  Could you please also let me know, how do I make sure the flatten function is working?  Thank you very much.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myTeamsCtrl', [function(){
        var self = this;

        var data = {"standings":[
            {
                "divisionName":"5th Grade - Green",
                "divisionStandings":[
                    {"teamId":3275,"teamName":"Severn Elite Gold","wins":3,"losses":1,"winningPct":".750","pointsFor":141,"pointsAgainst":126,"pointsDiff":15},
                    {"teamId":3220,"teamName":"HC Elite OMalley 5th","wins":3,"losses":1,"winningPct":".750","pointsFor":196,"pointsAgainst":191,"pointsDiff":5},
                    {"teamId":3277,"teamName":"MD 3D 5th","wins":2,"losses":2,"winningPct":".500","pointsFor":156,"pointsAgainst":132,"pointsDiff":24},
                    {"teamId":3222,"teamName":"Columbia Ravens 5th","wins":2,"losses":2,"winningPct":".500","pointsFor":147,"pointsAgainst":124,"pointsDiff":23},
                    {"teamId":3224,"teamName":"Team Dedication 5th","wins":2,"losses":2,"winningPct":".500","pointsFor":113,"pointsAgainst":123,"pointsDiff":-10},
                    {"teamId":4299,"teamName":"D1 Spartans","wins":0,"losses":0,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":0,"pointsAgainst":0,"pointsDiff":0}
                ]
            },
            {
                "divisionName":"5th Grade - White",
                "divisionStandings":[
                    {"teamId":3276,"teamName":"HC Elite 4th Tookes","wins":4,"losses":1,"winningPct":".800","pointsFor":187,"pointsAgainst":158,"pointsDiff":29},
                    {"teamId":3225,"teamName":"CBSA Hoyas 5th Grade","wins":2,"losses":2,"winningPct":".500","pointsFor":149,"pointsAgainst":133,"pointsDiff":16},
                    {"teamId":3226,"teamName":"Randelstown Runnin Rebels 5th","wins":1,"losses":3,"winningPct":".250","pointsFor":108,"pointsAgainst":155,"pointsDiff":-47},
                    {"teamId":3223,"teamName":"Up n Coming Clippers 5th","wins":0,"losses":0,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":0,"pointsAgainst":0,"pointsDiff":0},
                    {"teamId":3221,"teamName":"HC Elite Knisley 5th","wins":0,"losses":5,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":163,"pointsAgainst":218,"pointsDiff":-55}
                ]
            }
        ]};
        var teamId = '3221';
        var standingTeam = _.chain(data.standings)
                        .flatten("divisionStandings")
                        .find({'teamId', teamId})
                        .value();



        console.log(standing);

    }])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two bugs in your code:

1. You cannot find a teamId which is number with a value which is string
2. The object in `find` function is not well formed.

   ```
   teamId = 3221;

   standingTeam = _.chain(data.standings)
     .pluck('divisionStandings')
     .flatten()
     .find({ 'teamId': teamId })
     .value();

   console.log(standingTeam);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`flatten` is used to combine an array of arrays into one array (e.g. `[[1],[2]] -> [1,2]`).

It looks like you're trying to get all of the standings from all of the divisions and then find a single standing by id. Here's how you can do that:

```
_.chain(data.standings)
.pluck('divisionStandings')
.flatten()
.findWhere({ 'teamId': teamId })
.value()
```